# Listening for route events in Backbone not working – attached function is not called

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In a Backbone JS project, I am trying to listen for events emitted by the router. From the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Router):

> When the visitor presses the back button, or enters a URL, and a
>   particular route is matched, the name of the action will be fired as
>   an event, so that other objects can listen to the router, and be
>   notified.

Unfortunately, I can't get this to work, no matter if I use `on` or `listenTo` to listen for the router events.

The router looks like this:

```
var appRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    '' : 'index',
    'page(/:id)' : 'showPage'
  }
});

app.Router = new appRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
```

An in a view's initialize function, I try to listen for the events like this:

```
initialize: function () {
  this.listenTo(app.Router, 'route:showPage', this.myTestFn);
  app.Router.on('route:index', this.myTestFn);
},
```

To me, this looks correct, but `myTestFn` is never called.

How do I listen for route events in Backbone JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends if you are using hash or standard urls.

**Using hash urls**

Your setup is correct assuming you are using hash urls. So if you have links like the following ones, your code will work fine:

```
<a href="#">Index</a>
<a href="#page/1">First page</a>
```

I have quickly created a jsfiddle with your code and those links [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2wxvLL9j/1/)

**Using standard urls**

More work is needed if you are planning to use standard urls. Basically you will need to:

1. Initialize [Backbone history](http://backbonejs.org/#History) using HTML5 push state

   ```
   Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
   ```
2. Intercept the click events on your links, preventing the browser from sending a full GET request to your server. You could add events to your views or use a global event handler as [in this nice article](http://artsy.github.io/blog/2012/06/25/replacing-hashbang-routes-with-pushstate/).
3. Manually tell your backbone router to navigate to the intercepted link url

   ```
   app.Router.navigate(href, {trigger: true});
   ```

For example given the following urls:

```
<nav class="navLinks">
    <a href="/" class="standardUrlLink">Index</a>
    <a href="/page/1" class="standardUrlLink">First page</a>
</nav>
```

You could have a view like the following one:

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: ".navLinks",
    events: {
        "click .standardUrlLink": "standardUrlIntercepted"
    },
    initialize: function () {
      this.listenTo(app.Router, 'route:showPage', this.myTestFn);
      app.Router.on('route:index', this.myTestFn);
    },        
    standardUrlIntercepted: function(event) {
        //Get the link href and manually use backbone to navigate, triggering the route
        var href = $(event.currentTarget).attr("href");
        console.log("standard url intercepted, href=" + href);
        app.Router.navigate(href, {trigger: true});
        //Cancel default event behaviour (sending the GET request)
        return false;
    },
    myTestFn: function(){
        console.log("route called")
    }
});
```

I have put together a working example using this approach in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nzn7dz9t/) so you can try it.

Comment: I see, thank you! Now I know that puzzled me: On initial page load, the `route:foo` event won't fire, but any callback function inside the router will. Also custom events triggered there won't fire. That means it's not possible to attach an init type function directly to a route event.